# A function from one vector space to another that is non-linear

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is explained in the title. I am looking for a basic example of a function from one vector space to another that is non-linear

Comment: $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}; \; f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: $f:\{0\}\to\mathbb R$; $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would any non-linear mapping work? What about x^2 -> log(x)

Comment: Yes, any non-linear mapping would work, but it should probably be defined on the entire space. Generalising Jonas Meyer's excellent example, any nonzero constant function will do. Or $\sin x$, or ...

Answer (score 4):

View $\mathbb{R}$ as a real vector space, and consider the map sending $x$ to $x^2$.

---

In a general vector space with three distinct elements, consider a function which is the identity except for a specific non-zero vector $\vec{a}$; send $\vec a$ to $0$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, thanks for the correction.